# Делаю инвентарь в c#

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Делаю инвентарь в c# и я решил сделать 2 списка один с вещами, а другой инвентарь игрока, но я хз как добавлять туда вещи.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Inventory
    {
        public bool empty;
        public int number;
        public string name;
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Inventory> inventory = new List<Inventory>();
            
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                inventory.Add(new Inventory());
            }
        
            List<Inventory> Item = new List<Inventory>();
            Item.Add(new Inventory() { empty = true, number = 1, name = "шляпа" });
            Item.Add(new Inventory() { empty = true, number = 1, name = "камень" });
            Item.Add(new Inventory() { empty = true, number = 1, name = "меч" });
            
            foreach (Inventory i in inventory)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.empty);
                Console.WriteLine(i.number);
                Console.WriteLine(i.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что именно вам не понятно и что не получается? Да и как мы вам должны помочь в этом? Вы вроде уже вон знаете как добавлять в список  предметы, так вперед, добавляйте нужные в `List<Inventory> inventory`.

Comment: Извините в метаните не было так как в масив добавлять и я начал методом тыка пытаться, я создал тип все но пусто, а когда начал пытаться добавлять уже в пустые экземпляры класса сильно перепугался.

Comment: Если у вас строгое число элементов, то это уже скорей всего массив, а не коллекция. Самый "сок" в коллекциях, это в их динамичности, то есть вам не надо как массив пересоздавать их с нужным размером, а просто добавляете/удаляете объекты и он покажет сколько их там. И вот если эта динамичность вам не нужна, то берите простой массив N размера и по индексу тогда задавайте объект.

Comment: Я просто экспериментировал в игре хотел сделать бездонный инвентарь

Comment: Ну тогда зачем вам пустые объекты в динамичной коллекции? Просто инициализируйте ее без цикла `for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)` и дальше уже добавляйте/удаляйте что надо. Пустые объекты это бесполезный костыль в вашем случае.

Comment: Спасиб. Интересно почему у меня тут -1 хотя вопрос вроде как решен?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не очень хорош в плане информативности и полезности, другими словами, на мой взгляд, он бесполезен для SO и за это кто-то (не я) проголосовал против него.

Comment: обидка одним словом

Comment: Предполагаю, что минус за то что в вопросе нет вопроса. А так да, вы все правильно делаете `Item.Add(...)`, но пустые элементы добавлять туда не нужно.

Comment: Кста потом методом тыком я пришел к этому, лол (метод тыка тупо как описать всех новичков программистов)

Answer (score 0):

Путем биения головой об метанит и прочие руководства я нашел ответ, все просто как и с массивами.
Надо поставить это

```
inventory.Insert(0, item[0]);
```

перед foreach и все.

Comment: Квадратные скобки все порешали йеееее боииииии